# Powershell Subfolder sizes (MB/GB) to out-grid

Tags: powershell

So I'm trying to combine #1 and #2 to get the sub-folder sizes and put into an out-gridview with folder name and MB/GB sizes.  #3 works but it shows @name... vice just size mb/kb. looking for helping combining the two into one.

```
#1
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\" -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum | 
Select-Object @{Name="Size(kB)";Expression={("{0:N2}" -f($_.Sum/1kb))}}, 
@{Name="Size(MB)";Expression={("{0:N2}" -f($_.Sum/1mb))}}, 
@{Name="Size(GB)";Expression={("{0:N2}" -f($_.Sum/1gb))}} | 
Out-GridView

#2
Get-ChildItem -path "C:\" -Directory -Recurse | 
Select-Object FullName | 
ForEach-Object -Process{New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{Name =$_.FullName;Size = (Get-ChildItem -path $_.FullName -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum ).Sum/1kb}} | 
Select-Object Name, @{Name="Size(KB)";Expression={("{0:N2}" -f($_.Size))}}|
Out-Gridview



#3 - combine 1/2 and set variable path
#set path
$path = "c:\"

#GET Sizes sort MB/GB
Get-ChildItem -path "$path" -Directory -Recurse | 
Select-Object FullName | 
ForEach-Object -Process{New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{Name =$_.FullName;Size = (Get-ChildItem -path $_.FullName -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum)| 
Select-Object Name,
@{Name="Size(MB)";Expression={("{0:N2}" -f($_.Sum/1mb))}}, 
@{Name="Size(GB)";Expression={("{0:N2}" -f($_.Sum/1gb))}}  
}
}|
Out-GridView
```

Answer (score 0):

Break down your code and you will see where the issue is, this one of many reasons why indentation is important:

```sh
New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
    Name = $_.FullName
    Size = (
        Get-ChildItem -path $_.FullName -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
        Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum
    ) | Select-Object 'Name',
            @{Name="Size(MB)";Expression={("{0:N2}" -f($_.Sum/1mb))}},
            @{Name="Size(GB)";Expression={("{0:N2}" -f($_.Sum/1gb))}}  
}
```

The object produced by `New-Object` is the one passed to `Out-GridView`, this object will consist of 2 properties, `Name` and `Size`.

The **Value of the `Size` property** will be an object with 3 properties, `Name`, `Size(MB)` and `Size(GB)`.

The object would look similar to this when seen on the console:

```sh
Name Size
---- ----
foo  @{Name=foo; Size(MB)=0.00; Size(GB)=0.00}

# Size is stringified when seen in the console:
[pscustomobject]@{
    'Name'     = 'foo'
    'Size(MB)' = '0.00'
    'Size(GB)' = '0.00'
} -as [string]

# => @{Name=foo; Size(MB)=0.00; Size(GB)=0.00}
```

Here is an easier way you can get your desired output. Note the use of [`[pscustomobject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.2) to instantiate a new object, instead of `New-Object`. This method is faster and cleaner, however is only available on **PowerShell v3.0 and newer versions**.

```sh
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Directory -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $size = Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -File -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
        Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum
    [pscustomobject]@{
        "FullName" = $_.FullName
        "Name"     = $_.Name
        "Size(MB)" = "{0:N2}" -f ($size.Sum / 1Mb)
        "Size(GB)" = "{0:N2}" -f ($size.Sum / 1Gb)
    }
} | Out-GridView
```

I believe you're looking to get the folder's size based on the files inside them (non recursive), hence removing `-Recurse` and adding `-File`:

```sh
$size = Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -File -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum
```

Comment: Thanks for this; sadly my work environment only has authorized PS V1. So many of the blogs I have researched have all new commands. I'm also not very good at powershell but love what you can do with it.
Im still getting the same outout with the above script, and it is stopping at the root folder not getting the sub directories.

Comment: @Rob in that case you could replace `[pscustomobject]` for `New-Object`, I believe that should work. I personally have no idea what was available in PS v1.